# How to write a String to a file in small parts to save memory?

Tags: java, string, file, filewriter

So I have a really long string (about 20MB). I want to write this to a file but I don't want to load all of it in an Input stream as that takes lot of memory. I want to write the string in small parts (maybe 1 mb at a time?). Let's say I have :
`String data`
`File file`
I want to write `data` to `file` in small parts to save memory. Thank you and please let me know how I can improve the question.
Is it possible to use `FileChannel` somehow for this?

Comment: If you have a `String` then it's already in memory. Are you saying you have a 20MB `String` object?

Comment: Yess 20MB string object is already in memory. However I don't want to convert this entire 20MB string object into an input stream as that will increase my memory usage right ? I hope this makes it more clear ?

Comment: You should be able to open a `Writer` to the file and simply call its `#write(String)` method.

Comment: Will that lead to extra memory usage ? Will another copy of my 20mb string object be created in any form?

Comment: Yes, see Writer.write(String) which calls Writer.write(String,int,int), but I think that's inevitable if you're writing a String, as it will need to convert from the internal UTF-16 encoding to whatever encoding you decide to write it in.

Comment: @tgdavies What about that indicates a copy of the `String` is made?

Comment: `public void write(String str, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        char cbuf[] = new char[len];
        str.getChars(off, (off + len), cbuf, 0);
        write(cbuf, 0, len);
    }`

Comment: @CS2899 It might. If you're really worried about this I believe you can loop over the chars of the `String` and call `Writer#write(int)` repeatedly without having to worry about copies and buffers.

Comment: @tgdavies I just saw that in `OutputStreamWriter` / `StreamEncoder`. I find that a rather strange way to implement that method...

Comment: Yes, it actually has nothing to do with encoding, that's done much later. You'd think adding an optimised implementation when offset is zero and the length is the entire String would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`StringReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)) with a comfortably-sized `char[]` buffer into which to read it, then write that to file.